# is there a way to control the speed of a single state in unity through code?

Tags: c#

Hey so I have a animation controller with 3 animations , idle - walking - attacking , now I want to control the speed of walking animation through the code , I know you can do it via the inspector by I want to create sort of sprint and make the animation quicker , Btw I do not want to speed up the whole layer just the state of walking and through code , Thanks !

I tried to do :
public Animator animator; thats the refrence.
then i tried to do animator.speed but it controled every animation and thats not what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

My first question is why would you not just make another state where you duplicate the walk animation, adjust its speed, and then just set the state to that when you need a sprint animation.

If that isn't suitable for what you're going for though, the only way I can think to do it is to just check what the current animator clip is and adjust the speed accordingly:

```
float defaultSpeed;
float sprintSpeed = 2.0f;
[SerializeField]Animator animator;

void Start()
{
   defaultSpeed = animator.speed;
}

void Update()
{
    if (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0)[0].clip.name == "Walk")
    {
        animator.speed = sprintSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
       animator.speed = defaultSpeed;
    }
}
```

`